importance of pigments involved in photosynthesis
How do the accessory pigments(chl-b and carotenoids) help in during the process of photosynthesis? Can I please get a detailed explanation about it. I know that it helps in increasing the efficiency and protects chl-a present at the reaction center but how? Why all the shield pigments go to the excited state when only chl-a is needed to transfer the electron to the primary acceptor.

Hi and welcome. This is a good question, but on this site, evidence of research in an attempt to answer your own question (a quote and a link) is required. We don't know how much you already understand, and in order to avoid unnecessary explanations, we need to know the starting point of the answer. Wikipedia has articles on the various accessory pigments. A link to the one you are most basically confused by, and why the article doesn't answer your question, would help us give you the answer you need. There are entire books on photosynthesis. We can't write a chapter here as an answer.
